# How to write Countdown for powerpoint in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a Timer into powerpoint presentation. Once this timer will run off it should move to the next slide.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Sub countdown()

Dim time As Date
time = #10/5/2030 9:30:00 AM#
Do Until Hour(time) = Hour(Now()) And Minute(time) = Minute(Now()) And Second(time) = Second(Now())
DoEvents
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")
Loop

SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
End Sub
```

the issue is that I have to manually click on the element to start the timer. Is there a solution that would start a time on slide enter and would allow me to move to the next slide without crashing the PowerPoint?

Is there a possible solution using Sub OnSlideShowPageChange() event handler? I'm really new to VBA.

Thank you

Comment: >> Is there a possible solution using Sub OnSlideShowPageChange() event handler? ... Quite likely yes. Just change the name of your sub to OnSlideShowPageChange. Normally that's enough to fire the sub automatically; if not, add an ActiveX control (off the slide so it's not visible).  You'll need to add a bit more code if you want this to happen on only *some* slides but not all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to hook the behavior to the event OnSlideShowPageChange

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

Do While ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 1 Or ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 6 Or ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 7 Or ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = 8
    Dim time As Date
    
    Select Case SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition
     Case 1
            time = #10/5/2030 9:30:00 AM#
     Case 6
            time = #10/5/2030 10:40:00 AM#
     Case 7
            time = #10/5/2030 11:00:00 AM#
     Case 8
            time = #10/5/2030 11:00:00 AM#
    End Select
 
    If Hour(time) = Hour(Now()) And Minute(time) = Minute(Now()) And Second(time) = Second(Now()) Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("Countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")
Loop
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
End Sub
```

but now it looks like the event is blocked with no possibility to end if somebody would move slide forward == the presentation would hang up and error out...

is there a possible solution to break when presentation leaves the current slide if the loop is running?

Comment: This is not an answer - it would be better to edit your question

Answer (score 0):

To write a [countdown](https://anuragdigital.com/) timer in VBA for PowerPoint, you can use the following code:

1. Open PowerPoint and press "Alt + F11" to open the VBA editor.
2. Insert a new module by clicking on "Insert" > "Module".
3. In the module, write the following code:

```vb
Sub StartCountdown()
    Dim TimeInSeconds As Integer
    Dim SlideIndex As Integer
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim TextBox As Shape
    
    ' Set the countdown time in seconds
    TimeInSeconds = 60
    
    ' Set the slide index where you want the countdown timer
    SlideIndex = 1
    
    ' Check if the slide index is valid
    If SlideIndex > 0 And SlideIndex <= ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Then
        ' Create or update the countdown timer textbox
        Set Slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)
        Set TextBox = Slide.Shapes("CountdownTimer")
        If TextBox Is Nothing Then
            Set TextBox = Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 50)
            TextBox.Name = "CountdownTimer"
        End If
        TextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TimeInSeconds
        
        ' Start the countdown
        Do While TimeInSeconds > 0
            TextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TimeInSeconds
            TimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds - 1
            DoEvents ' Allows the slide to update while counting down
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Loop
        
        ' Remove the countdown timer textbox
        TextBox.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid slide index."
    End If
End Sub
```

4. Modify the `TimeInSeconds` variable to set the desired countdown time.
5. Modify the `SlideIndex` variable to specify the slide where you want the countdown timer to appear.
6. Optionally, you can modify the position and size of the countdown timer textbox by adjusting the parameters in `Shapes.AddTextbox` method.
7. Save the VBA module.
8. To start the countdown, press "Alt + F8" to open the macro dialog, select "StartCountdown", and click "Run".

Make sure you have a textbox shape named "CountdownTimer" on the designated slide for the countdown timer to appear.